# reticulate python engine - Use r as a name for Python object shared between multiple chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, reticulate

I am writing an R Markdown document using the Python engine of {reticulate}. I am quite happy with how it works.

The only thing is, I cannot use `r` as a Python object name that I'm going to use in multiple chunks.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## Object name `r`

```{python}
r = 10
print(r)  ##> 10
```

```{python}
print(r)  ##> <__main__.R object at 0x119ad37d0>
```
````

I understand `r` is a good name when we use R objects from within a Python chunk. Since I know I am not going to do that in my project, I would like to use `r` as a name for my Python object.

**Is there any way to change the name, `r`,  for the `R` object created by reticulate? Or, to tell reticulate not to create `r` object?**

I am aware of the two straightforward workarounds

1. Don't use `r` for Python objects.
2. Write everything in one big chunk and not share `r` between Python chunks.

but I'd like to have more freedom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object name `r` is special since it is used to communicate between R and python. The same holds for `py` in R:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## Object name `r`

```{python}
foo = 10
print(foo)  ##> 10
```

```{r}
library(reticulate)
py$foo ##> [1] 10
```

```{r}
foo <- 10
```

```{python}
print(foo) ##> 10
print(r.foo) ##> 10.0
```
````

Avoiding the use of `r` as an opject name is therefore the only good possibility I can see.

Comment: It's a shame... I had the same impression when I saw "r = R()" hard-coded in the source code... although I don't quite understand most of it. https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/0ad258495b95cf026488314f62a6bb8fdae41f76/R/python.R#L1403  But I thank you for your reply!

Comment: I have decided to work around this issue (at least to me) by defining a custom knit_hook option that I set with a temporary variable name like `rrr`. And the temp variable name is replaced with desired `r` in source and output code, after execution. This seems to be enough for me.

Comment: @Kenji Interesting. How about adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Still working on the details but I think setting source and output knit hooks may help. My dirty first try looks like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(
  source = function(x, options) {
    if (!is.null(options$rsub)) x = gsub(options$rsub, 'r', x, fixed = TRUE)
    sprintf('<div class="%s"><pre class="knitr %s">%s</pre></div>\n', "source", tolower(options$engine), x)
  },
  output = function(x, options) {
    if (!is.null(options$rsub)) x = gsub(options$rsub, 'r', x, fixed = TRUE)
    paste0('<pre><code>', x, '</code></pre>\n')
  }
)
```


```{python, rsub='rrr'}
rrr = 10
print(rrr)
```

```{python, rsub='rrr'}
print(rrr)
```
````